# Cheap wifi for embedded projects

Tags: wifi, stm32

I am looking to combine a cheap wifi baseband/mac chipset with a STM32 F1 or F2 MCU to run the IP stack.

I have to use the cheap USB wifi dongles or use SDIO/SPI interface and port the drivers.

I am facing a problem in finding the correct chipset which has datasheets / opensource drivers to continue with this work. The problem with Atheros / Broadcomm is they do not give datasheet unless an NDA is signed.

My only requirement is the chipset should be able to act as "Access point" for initial configuration.

Comment: If you want to use a USB dongle, you'll need a chip with a USB host interface, such as the F4.  I don't believe that's available in the F2 series - generally the lower end parts have at most a USB device interface.  Also, not all dongles support Master mode to be an access point.

Comment: What is "cheap" here ? What is your budget ? What are your volumes ? The Athros and Broadcomm of the world are not structured to deal with low volume users, so your observations about lack of datasheet is quite spot-on. Also, are you really stuck to STM32 F1/F2 MCU's ? Or are you open to exploring alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize its been 4 years after this question has been asked, but here's one worth considering (as of 2017).

[ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) or its successor [ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32).

- Can be interfaced via USART + AT commands or directly programmed using a [port](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino) for Arduino IDE
- Available on aliexpress/ebay for about $2 for the minimal board (ESP-01)
- Available in multiple board [configurations](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266-module-family)
- Specs can be found [here](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=feature_set)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give a try to the one that is advised for Rasberry-pi. I have never tested it for such purposes but should be fine. Here is a link to buy it: [Wipi](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=2133900#)

Comment: This would require a USB host interface, which I don't believe the mentioned microcontrollers possess.  It could also likely require more software support that will fit in their memory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe TI CC3000 is worth trying. It looks like an all in one module (Embedded IP stack) and said to be able to work with low speed/memory MCUs such as MSP430. It has SPI host interface. Here is the wiki page http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3000 . Also there is a development module  https://estore.ti.com/CC3000EM-CC3000-Evaluation-Module-P4257.aspx which you can connect to TI Launchpads.